# How to use whoosh for searching keywords

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, whoosh

Article Schema:

Below is the article schema what I have created.

```
class ArticleSchema(SchemaClass):
    title = TEXT(
        phrase=True, sortable=True, stored=True,
        field_boost=2.0, spelling=True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer())
    keywords = KEYWORD(
        commas=True, field_boost=1.5, lowercase=True)
    authors = KEYWORD(stored=True, commas=True, lowercase=True)
    content = TEXT(spelling=True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer())
    summary = TEXT(spelling=True, analyzer=StemmingAnalyzer())
    published_time = DATETIME(stored=True, sortable=True)
    permalink = STORED
    thumbnail = STORED
    article_id = ID(unique=True, stored=True)
    topic = TEXT(spelling=True, stored=True)
    series_id = STORED
    tags = KEYWORD(commas=True, lowercase=True)
```

Search Query

```
FIELD_TIME = 'published_time'
FIELD_TITLE = 'title'
FIELD_PUBLISHER = 'authors'
FIELD_KEYWORDS = 'keywords'
FIELD_CONTENT = 'content'
FIELD_TOPIC = 'topic'

def search_query(search_term=None, page=1, result_len=10):
    '''Search the provided query.'''
    if not search_term or search_term == '':
        return None, 0
    if not index.exists_in(INDEX_DIR, indexname=INDEX_NAME):
        return None, 0
    ix = get_index()
    parser = qparser.MultifieldParser(
            [FIELD_TITLE, FIELD_PUBLISHER, FIELD_KEYWORDS, FIELD_TOPIC],
            ix.schema)
    query = parser.parse(search_term)
    query.normalize()
    search_results = []
    with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        results = searcher.search_page(
            query,
            pagenum=page,
            pagelen=result_len,
            sortedby=[sorting_timestamp, scores],
            reverse=True,
            terms=True
        )
        if results.scored_length() > 0:
            for hit in results:
                search_results.append(append_to(hit))
            return (search_results, results.pagecount)

    parser = qparser.MultifieldParser(
            [FIELD_TITLE, FIELD_PUBLISHER, FIELD_TOPIC],
            ix.schema, termclass=FuzzyTerm)
    parser.add_plugin(qparser.FuzzyTermPlugin())
    query = parser.parse(search_term)
    query.normalize()
    search_results = []
    with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        results = searcher.search_page(
            query,
            pagenum=page,
            pagelen=result_len,
            sortedby=[sorting_timestamp, scores],
            reverse=True,
            terms=True
        )
        if results.scored_length() > 0:
            for hit in results:
                search_results.append(append_to(hit))
            return (search_results, results.pagecount)
    return None, 0
```

When I am trying the title search is working, but for author and keyword the search is not working. I am not able to understand what wrong I am doing here. I am getting data from api and then running the index. It's all working fine. But when I am searching through keywords like `authors` and `keywords` it's not working.

Comment: Please give an example for what you store in authors and what you search.

Answer (score 0):

Both `authors` and `keywords` are of type `KEYWORD` which does not support phrase search which mean that you should search with the exact keyword or one of its derivatives since you are using a stemmer.

For `authors`, I think you should use `TEXT`.

From whoosh documentation

> **whoosh.fields.KEYWORD**
>
> This type is designed for space- or comma-separated keywords. This
>   type is indexed and searchable (and optionally stored). To save space,
>   **it does not support phrase searching**.